# Accessing source codes to modify Linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm a beginner at Linux kernel. I have to modify the Linux driver for a project.

how do I access the source code files (such as ani.c, ath9k.h, etc.)?

I tried looking for them in the following path, but I only found kernel object files (*.ko).

PATH: drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to find them [on Linus's GitHub account](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). You might find the guides linked from ["Working with the kernel development community"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/index.html) helpful too.

Comment: I already have an installed kernel version, but I'm just having some difficulties finding the source codes that I need to modify. I'm assuming that those source codes (such as the ones listed in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k) are in "/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/" of my device. However, I'm unable to find them there. How do we access the source codes after installing the kernel? What is the default directory where we can find them?

Comment: By default only the compiled form of the kernel is downloaded, to save space. (The kernel source tree takes up around 800MB these days.) You can find a tag in the source repository for the version that's installed on your machine (see, for example, [the 4.19 tag](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v4.19)), but you'll have to download and recompile the source anyway.